# try to add structur element in a text file without overwrite it

Tags: c++, text-files, overwrite

```
void addToTextfile()
{
    Students stud[20];
    Students stdt;
    ifstream myFile;

    myFile.open("student.txt", fstream::app);

    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "\t\t\tStudent KNumber     =>  ";
        cin >> stdt.KNumber;
        cout << "\t\t\tStudent Name        =>  ";
        cin >> stdt.StudentName;

        myFile << stdt.KNumber << stdt.StudentName << endl;

    }
    myFile.close();
}
```

get error =>

> Error  1   error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your file variable to use `fstream`.  The `ifstream` is for **i**nput.  The `ofstream` is for **o**utput.  The `fstream` is used for both input and output.

The `operator<<` is for output.  You can't output to an input stream (don't enter the exit door).